# Vlookup between 2 sheets - text lookup from source sheet to target not fetching result

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

```
        Dim rw as long
        Dim lookupvalue as string
        Dim targetlookupvalue as variant
        Dim wbthis as workbook
        Dim countrywbrange as range

        With wbThis.ActiveSheet

             For rw = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                lookupvalue = Cells(rw, 5)
                On Error Resume Next

                     Cells(rw, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupvalue, countrywbrange, 4, False)
                      countrywbrange.Select
                      MsgBox lookupvalue & Cells(rw, 3)

                      targetlookupvalue = Cells(rw, 3)

                     If (IsEmpty(targetlookupvalue)) Then
                    MsgBox "WIP targetvalue is empty"


                    Else
                    MsgBox "proceed"

                End If

            Next rw

          End With
```

I am trying to refer country codes to fetch countries from another sheet, but the variant variable always returns empty. Lookupvalue returns the value to be fetched, I am unable to understand what is the error. Request you experts to help with this.

Comment: `I am unable to understand what is the error.` How will you understand the error when you are telling Excel to "Shut the F@#$ up" :). `On Error Resume Next` does exactly that. Handle the errors correctly

Comment: Haha thanks bro. Such a stupid error.